# Mobile Push Tracking in CRM

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, mobilepush

Currently we are implementing Mobile Push and would like the tracking data go back to CRM.I see an option of sending the data using data views but realized the OTB data views arent providing any metric which actually helps business make a calculative decision.

Any other options or ways ?

Note : we want the tracking data to be shown in CRM only.

Comment: Marketing Cloud Connect doesn’t support sending any mobile tracking data back to CRM ootb. You’d have to build a custom integration for that.

Comment: @zuzannamj Could he build a custom object in SF CRM and then push to Marketing Cloud. Then use automation studio to grab the Mobile Push data, insert into the object, and then sync back to CRM?